# Add rotated watermark text with background to image in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, bufferedimage, graphics2d, watermark

I am using Java 8 (Spring Boot), and I want to add text (as watermark) to an image like this:

[image: example]

As you see, the text `HELLO WORLD!` is **rotated 90 degrees**, and it has **black background color** (the grey background is a source image).

Here is my current Java code that adds text to an image in center (no background, not rotated):

```java
public BufferedImage AddTextWatermarkInCenter(BufferedImage targetImg, String watermarkText) {
    Graphics2D targetImgGraphics = (Graphics2D)targetImg.getGraphics();
    
    // Init graphic properties
    AlphaComposite alphaComposite = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1.0f);
    targetImgGraphics.setComposite(alphaComposite);
    targetImgGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    targetImgGraphics.setFont(WatermarkImageHelper.AcquireWatermarkFont());
    
    FontMetrics targetImgFontMetrics = targetImgGraphics.getFontMetrics();
    Rectangle2D targetImgRectangle = targetImgFontMetrics.getStringBounds(watermarkText, targetImgGraphics);
    
    // Calculates the coordinate where the text is painted
    int centerX = ((targetImg.getWidth() - (int)targetImgRectangle.getWidth()) / 2);
    int centerY = (targetImg.getHeight() / 2);
    
    // Paints the textual watermark
    targetImgGraphics.drawString(watermarkText, centerX, centerY);
    
    targetImgGraphics.dispose();
    
    return targetImg;
}
```

How do I draw watermark text as the example image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `AffineTransform` to rotate the Graphics.

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Rotate extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();

        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );
        g2.setFont( new Font( "Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 12 ) );

        for( double angle = 0; angle <= 90; angle+=30 )
        {
            String text = "Rotate angle is " + (int)angle;
            AffineTransform af = new AffineTransform();
            af.translate(50, 50);
            af.rotate( Math.toRadians( angle ) );
            g2.setTransform( af );

            g2.setColor( Color.black );
            g2.drawString(text, 50, 0);
            g2.setColor( Color.red );
            g2.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 0 );
        }

        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rotate");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Rotate());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But this doesn't draw the black background around the text

Comment: We are not here to write the entire code for you. I was assuming your issue was with the rotation.  Most people know the basics of using the `drawString(...)` or `fillRect(...)` methods. Post your [mre] showing what you tried if you need more help.

Comment: I'm not asking the full code.  So from your code, I guess I need to trigger `g2.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 0 );` multiple times to draw the black background color?  I marked your post as the answer though.  Thanks!

Comment: The example showed how to do the rotation using the drawString(...) and drawLine(...) methods. You are not limited to those methods. You can use any of the Grraphics painting methods to achieve your desired effect. I suggested the fillRect(...) method.